# How to send an Notification e-mail in UrbanCode deploy?

Tags: email, notifications

I am working on IBM UrbanCode Deploy. I want send an e-mail notification from UrbanCode Deploy regarding the deployment status. I am unable to configure the e-mail notification for that.

How can I send an e-mail to a developer or a person about the deployment status through UrbanCode Deploy?

Can any one help me about this in a detailed manner?

Answer (score 0):

sure you can try the plugin

[plugin link](https://hub.jazz.net/project/ucplugin/UrbanCode%20Deploy%20Plug-in%20for%20Sending%20Email/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/project/ucplugin/UrbanCode%2520Deploy%2520Plug-in%2520for%2520Sending%2520Email/ucplugin%2520%257C%2520UrbanCode%2520Deploy%2520Plug-in%2520for%2520Sending%2520Email/_2CqvAHS3EeOEAdgB1rj08Q/_2D1zsHS3EeOEAdgB1rj08Q/SendingEmail)